# SelectOneMenu fire ajax when up or down arrow key is pressed

Tags: ajax, jsf

I need to fire an ajax call when i hit the up arrow key or the down arrow key when im focused on the selectOneMenu.

Here is my code, i tried only with the up key first (Its not working, and i tried several variations)

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="id" disabled="#!Bean.disabled}" value="#{Bean.value}" styleClass="style" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 38) { onchange(); return false; }">
  <f:selectItems id="idItem" value="#{Bean.options}" var="option" />
  <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="group"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Hint: Tab key is firing it and moving the focus (if the value changed). I dont want the tab key firing it.

Comment: did you tried the code below ?

Comment: @Tarik I will try it and let you know, thanks for your quick answer, i guess it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the event of your `f:ajax` to `keyup`, the `change` event will not send any ajax request unless your `selectOneMenu` loses focus (that's also confirmed by your hint "Tab key is firing it and moving the focus ").

That will work like this:

```
<f:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" render="group"/>
```

### Update:

I updated my answer following BalusC's comment that the you want the ajax request to be fired only if the up Key or down Key are fired, so i am suggesting you to invoke directly the javascript function that `f:ajax` calls behind the scenes, So you can add a direct call to `jsf.ajax.request(source, event, options)` function, you can find more informations about that function [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#.request).

In order to use that method you must add the JSF’s built-in JavaScript library in your XHTML files like this:

```
<h:outputScript library="javax.faces" name="jsf.js"/>
```

Then change your code like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="id" disabled="#!Bean.disabled}" value="#{Bean.value}" styleClass="style" 
         onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40) { jsf.ajax.request(this, event, { render: 'form:group'}); return false;}">
   <f:selectItems id="idItem" value="#{Bean.options}" var="option" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**NB:** Please notice that in the `render` option of the `jsf.ajax.request()` i specified the exact `ClientID` of the component you want to render and not only the component id (`form` is here the id of `h:form`), if you want to use only the id `group` you must add `prependId="false"` to your `h:form`.

Comment: OP only want to fire it when specifically up or down arrow is pressed.

Comment: @BalusC i modified my answer, thanks for the guidance :)

Comment: It works! I had to add an onclick event, with the same javascript except for the key codes filters, because i wanted to be fired with the click too. Thanks @Tarik and @BalusC!